# Proving $K$ is a group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, functions, binary-operations, associativity

Now I have proved certain things are a group before, and I know that it requires:

1)Associativity

2)Inverse

3)Identity

But here I have such a strange thing that I wanted to clarify that I am doing it right.

> If $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ with $a\ne0$, let $L_{a,b}:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be the function given by $L_{a,b}(x) = ax+b$ for all $x$. Let
>
> $$K = \{L_{a,b}|a,b\in \mathbb{R}\}$$
>
> Prove that $K$ forms a group under composition of functions.

So normally you want to test some operation binary operation like $x+y = x+y+2xy$ or something, and see if it meets the above $3$ requirements. But here I don't know if I want to look at associativity in which of the following ways:

1) $ ((ax+b) + (cy+d))+(ez+f) = (ax+b) + ((cy+d)+(ez+f))$

2) $ ((ax+b) + (cx+d))+(ex+f) = (ax+b) + ((cx+d)+(ex+f))$

3) $ ((ax+b) + (ay+b))+(az+b) = (ax+b) + ((ax+b)+(ax+b))$

4) $ ((ax+b) + (ax+b))+(ax+b) = (ax+b) + ((ax+b)+(ax+b))$

Which one am I meant to be comparing?

How do I get the Inverse and Identity our? Does $L_{a,b}$ have some $x$ such that $ax+b=ax+b$, so just $x=x$ for identity, and some $ax+b=x$?

Comment: Function composition is always associative.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We need to remember we the group operation is *function composition*, and not function addition.

So to establish associativity, we need to establish that $$(L_{a,b}\circ L_{c,d})\circ L_{e,f}=L_{a,b}\circ (L_{c,d}\circ L_{e,f})$$

---

**Associativity**

$$\begin{align} (L_{a,b}\circ L_{c,d})\circ L_{e,f} 
& = (L_{a, b}(cx + d))\circ L_{e, f}\\ 
& = [a(cx + d) + b] \circ L_{e, f}\\
& =[acx + ad+b]\circ L_{e, f}\\ 
& = L_{ac, ad+b}(ex + f) \\
&=ac(ex+f) + (ad+b) \\ 
&= a(cex+cf +d) + b\\
& =L_{a, b}\circ (cex + cf + d)\\  
& = L_{a, b} \circ [c(ex+f) + d ]\\  
&=L_{a, b} \circ(L_{c, d}( ex + f))\\ 
& = L_{a, b}\circ(L_{c, d} \circ L_{e, f})
\end{align}$$

**Identity**

$$L_{\text{id}}(x) = x = 1\cdot x + 0 = L_{1, 0}$$

**Inverses**

Let $L_{a, b}(x) = y =ax + b$ be any element in the group. Solve for $y$: $$y-b = ax \iff \frac{y-b}{a} = x$$

So $$L^{-1}_{a, b}(x) = \frac{x-b}{a} = \frac 1a\cdot x + \left(\frac{-b}a\right) = L_{\frac 1a, \frac{-b}a}$$
You can confirm that $L_{\frac 1a, \frac{-b}{a}}(x) = L^{-1}_{a, b}(x)$ by composing the two functions and obtaining the identity function: $L_{1, 0}$.

Comment: Function composition is always associative.

Answer (score 5):

**None** of them. Rememeber the group operation is *composition of functions*, not pointwise addition.

You need to check $(L_{a,b}\circ L_{c,d})\circ L_{e,f}=L_{a,b}\circ (L_{c,d}\circ L_{e,f})$ as functions of $x$.

Comment: Does $x$ vary?${}$

Comment: @user142198 Two functions $f$ and $g$ are equal iff $f(x)=g(x)$ for all $x$.

Comment: @blue The "of $x$" is misleading, $L_{a,b}$ is a function of $x$ as well as a function of $t$, $z$ or whatever you want to name your variable. So "as functions" is enough.

Comment: @Pece Would I be right in saying that:
Identity: $L_{c,d} = x$
Inverse: $L_{c,d} = \frac{x-b}a$

here?

Comment: @Exam: It's strange to write $L_{c,d}$ for something that does not depend on $c$ or $d$…

Comment: @Examin5days Honestly I couldn't work out the inverse and stuff, so I gave up.

Comment: @user142198 To invert $L_{a,b}$, write $x=ay+b$ and solve for $y$. First, subtract $b$ to get $x-b=ay$, the divide by $a$ to get $y=a^{-1}x-a^{-1}b$. Hence $L_{a,b}^{-1}=L_{a^{-1},a^{-1}b}$.

Answer (score 0):

Your question essentially boils down to: "What do elements of $K$ look like?" The answer is obvious from the definition of $K$ and $L_{a,b}$. Each element in $K$ is a degree one polynomial with arbitrary coefficients and constants in $\mathbb R$. So, we see that 2) is the claim you wish to prove. Also, note that the operation defined on $K$ is function composition and not function addition.

Comment: +1 for "function composition", -1 for "the answer is obvious".